# How to initiate a var which will store array of values with different datatypes?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I have a dynamic expression built in .net, which works if the column type is string, however, if the column is date or int then i have to convert the input to the respective datatype before passing to the expression. How can I make it dynamic?

```
    MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.Name);
    var propertyType = ((PropertyInfo)member.Member).PropertyType;
    
    if (propertyType.GetType() == typeof(Int32))
    {
      var criteria = Array.ConvertAll(filter.Value, Int32.Parse);
    }
    else if (propertyType.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
    {
      var criteria = Array.ConvertAll(filter.Value, DateTime.Parse);
    }
    else
    {
    var criteria = filter.Value;
    }

criteria.Aggregate( // -- gives error here since criteria does not exist in current context
    (Expression)Expression.Constant(false),
        (acc, next) =>
        Expression.MakeBinary(
        ExpressionType.Or,
        acc, Expression.Equal(member, Expression.Constant(next))));
```

I already tried defining

```
var criteria = null;
var criteria = object[];
dynamic criteria;
var criteria = new {};
```

Payload

```
{
  "pageFilters": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "condition": "Equals",
      "value": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This feels like an XY problem to me, why are you doing this with an expression in the first place? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: i am building a dynamic filter/search in which i will pass filter criteria(posted in the question) which has column name, condition and search value

Comment: _i am building a dynamic filter/search_ - isn't it what Entity Framework or any other ORM already doing? :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t get what you are saying here